# Backbone.js setTimeout() loop in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

Seems like every way I try this, it throws some sort of error.  Here's what my code looks like now:

```
runShow: ->
  moments = @model.get('moment_stack_items')
  if inc == moments.length
    inc = 1
    pre = 0
  $("#" + moments[pre].uid).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000)
  $("#" + moments[inc].uid).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000)

  inc += 1
  pre += 1

  console.log "looping" + inc
  t = setTimeout(this.runShow(),2000);
```

I call the function in my events.
I have `inc = 1` and `pre = 0` defined outside the Backbone.View.. My current error is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'runShow'"
BONUS POINTS: how can I reference t from another function (to run my clearTimeout(t))?

Comment: Using strings in your setTimeout is calling eval behind the scenes.  I would strongly consider changing this to a reference of the function. e.g.   t = setTimeout(this.runShow ,2000);  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: fair enough @Gazler, I've removed it from the code.  The solution by user576875 also has it removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask the setTimeout function to evaluate `"this.runShow()"`, and setTimeout will do that in the context of `window`. This means that `this` is the `window` object when this code is evaluated.

To avoid this you can create a function and bind it to a the current context, so that everytime the function is called, `this` is the same as when the function has been created.

In coffee script you can do this with the [`=>`](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow):

```
func = =>
    this.runShow()

setTimeout(func, 2000)
```

Or on a single line:

```
setTimeout((=> this.runShow()), 2000)
```

> how can I reference t from another function?

Make `t` a property of your object:

```
class Something
    t: null
    runShow: ->
       ...
       this.t = ...
    otherFunction: ->
       t = this.t
```

Comment: Brilliant solution @user576875. Thanks for responding so quickly! I hadn't even thought to use =>

Comment: I actually prefer what you had before your edit! Much more concise and looked cleaner in my backbone view.

Comment: You mean this syntax: `setTimeout((=> this.runShow()), 2000)` ?

Comment: Yea, It just looks cleaner to me.